# Viewing progressive web applications on mobile screen sizes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, windows, window

I am developing a Next-based progressive web application through VSCode and am currently viewing the window through a desktop application. However, I cannot resize the window to mobile screen size and the only way I've been able to test the mobile view is through the mobile view feature on inspect element. This solution is undesirable because it makes the actual application very small due to all the padding from other UI components in the inspect element view (ex. console, settings, device selection)

Is there a way to force the screen size through the `meta` file or CSS? I have tried setting the maximum width through global styling, but I made the mistake of using `!w-screen` (tailwind) throughout my application and so it may be difficult to refactor

Some alternative solutions that might work:

- Being able to view the locally hosted application through a mobile device
- Reducing the minimum window size on Windows 10

Constraint: I do not want to use JQuery

Comment: Did you try getting your pc LAN address with your phone over your wifi? Something like `192.168.X.YYY:ZZZZ` usually works...

Comment: Do you know if this will work with an application that depends on a database? I'm trying it right now but can't connect

Comment: Database is not a factor. If you can view your app on `localhost:ZZZZ`... Then you should be able to reach it with the pc LAN address and the same port.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to make the mobile view feature more desirable by either detaching or minimizing the console and/or using the browsers zoom to get the viewport to a usable size. Refactoring code or adjusting CSS by wrapping the application might work, but seems counter productive if your goal is to gauge what it will look like (without?) those changes.